# Assistance on making a class for a pre-made demo file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently working on an assignment that requires me to create a "bottle class" for a pre-made "bottle demo" file my professor made. This is the description of the assignment:

> Write a Bottle class. The class has these 14 methods: read(), set(int), >set(Bottle), get(), and(Bottle), subtract(Bottle), multiply(Bottle), >divide(Bottle), add(int), subtract(int), multiply(int), divide(int), >equals(Bottle), and toString(). The toString() method will be given in class. All >add, subtract, multiply, and divide methods return a Bottle. Your Bottle class >must guarantee bottles always have a positive value and never exceed a maximum >number chosen by you. These numbers are declared as constants of the class. Each >method wit ha parameter must be examined to determine if the upper or lower bound >could be violated. Consider each method carefully and test only the conditions >that could be violated.

And here is the demo code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        bottle bottle1 = new bottle();
        bottle bottle2 = new bottle();
        bottle bottle3 = new bottle();
        bottle bottle4 = new bottle();
        bottle bottle5 = new bottle();
        System.out.println("please enter a number for bottle1:");
        bottle1.read(); // affected my max and min
        System.out.println("Bottle1 is this value " + bottle1 + ".");
        System.out.println("Please enter a number for bottle2:");
        bottle2.read();  // affected by max and min
        bottle3.set(0);
        bottle3 = bottle3.add(bottle1);
        bottle3 = bottle3.add(bottle2);
        bottle3 = bottle3.divide(2);
        System.out.println("The 2 bottle average is: " + bottle3 + ".");
        System.out.print("Subtracting bottle1 from bottle2 is: " );
        bottle3 = bottle2.subtract(bottle1);
        System.out.println( bottle3);
        bottle3 = bottle2.divide(bottle1);
        System.out.println("Dividing bottle2 with bottle1 is: " + bottle3 +     ".");
        if (bottle1.equals(bottle2))
        {
        System.out.println("Bottle1 and bottle2 are equal.");
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("Bottle1 and bottle2 are not equal.");
        }
        System.out.println("Bottle4 is now given the value of 10 with the  set() method.");
        bottle4.set(10);
        System.out.println("The value of bottle4 is " + bottle4 + ".");
        System.out.println("Bottle4 is now multiplied with bottle1. The value is placed in bottle5.");
        bottle5 = bottle1.multiply(bottle4);
        System.out.println("The value of bottle5 is " + bottle5 + ".");
        System.out.println("Enter an integer to add to the value bottle1 has.");
        System.out.println("The sum will be put in bottle3.");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = keyboard.nextInt();
        bottle3 = bottle1.add(x);
        System.out.println("Adding your number " + x +
        " to bottle1 gives a new Bottle with " + bottle3 + " in it.");
        System.out.print("Adding the number " + bottle2 + " which is the number" +
        " in bottle2 to the\nnumber in ");
        bottle2 = bottle1.add(bottle2);
        System.out.println("bottle1 which is " + bottle1 +" gives " + bottle2 + ".");

    }

}
```

And this is the code I have made so far:

```
public class bottle {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private int value;

    public void Bottle() {

    value = 0;
    }
    public void read() {
    value = scan.nextInt();
    }
    public void set(bottle) {
    value = bottle1.value;
    }
    public void set(int bottle1) {
    value = bottle1;
    }
    public bottle add(bottle) {
    value = value + bottle1.value;

    }
    public bottle subtract(bottle) {


    }
    public bottle multiply(bottle) {


    }
    public bottle divide(bottle) {


    }
    public bottle add(int bottle) {


    }
    public bottle subtract(int bottle) {


    }
    public bottle multiply(int bottle) {

    }
    public bottle divide(int bottle) {
    value = value / bottle;

    }
    public String toString() {
    String name = null;
    return name;
    }
    public boolean equals(bottle bottle) {
    if (this == bottle) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

What I need help on is how do I get my methods to work? ( add(int), divide(bottle), divide(int), etc)

And for there to be a max and min for values the user can input, I know that it can be placed at the top of the class code, but how do I make it so that every time the user inputs a number and the math outputs that the max and min will be checked every time to see if any number violates the set rule?

My I know my class code is missing many key components (I think return methods for the math parts) but I am struggling to stay sane trying to figure out what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

I will also answer any questions that you might have to the best of my ability.

EDIT: I have remade my code after reading the chapter about classes in my textbook and my knowledge is a bit better than before. Here is my new code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private int value;
private int max = 100;
private int min = 0;

public bottle() {
 // sets default value as zero
    this.value = 0;
}
public void read() {
    value = scan.nextInt();
}
public void set(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}    
public int add(bottle) {
    if (this.value + bottle < this.max && this.value + bottle > this.min)
        return this.value + bottle;
    else
        System.out.println("Please enter another number");
        int x =  scan.nextInt();
        return add(x);
    // the few lines above checks to see if the number violates the max and min

}
public int subtract(bottle) {
    if (this.value - bottle < this.max && this.value - bottle > this.min)
        return this.value - bottle;
    else 
        System.out.println("Please enter another number");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        return subtract(x);

}
// though there is this error under the word bottle in the parentheses
public int multiply(bottle) {
    if (this.value * bottle < this.max && this.value * bottle > this.min)
        return this.value * bottle;
    else 
        System.out.println("Please enter another number");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        return multiply(x);
}


public int divide(bottle) {
    if (this.value / bottle < this.max && this.value / bottle > this.min)
        return this.value / bottle;
    else 
        System.out.println("Please enter another number");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        return divide(x);

}
// the String toString method, format as shown by the professor.
public String toString()
{
    return this.max + " " + this.min + " " + this.value;
```

Though I still have 4 errors in my class which is the word bottle inside the parentheses after my add, subtract, multiply, and divide method. Thus the demo file has 8 errors which are all the math methods. I am not sure what to do because "bottle" is an object right? Then how do I add 2 bottles together, or am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: This sounds meaningless.  e.g. `add (int)`  is a method on a `Bottle`, that takes a `int` and returns a `Bottle` (`this` ?)

Comment: Just a quick note, class names should use PascalCase. (Capital first letters of every word (eg `Bottle`, or `BigMac`)) Also, why do your math functions return a `bottle`?

Comment: Why does your question have random ">" everywhere.

Comment: after a few days and reading the chapter in my textbook on classes I have re-edited my code:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're almost on the right track. These will help:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Pay attention to what an instance is and also how passing in arguments to methods works along with returning.

Comment: Many thanks for the links. Will take me some time for me to go through and figure out what I am getting wrong.